# Pandas how to mege the list of columns with NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge the columns that have the list objects.

The problem is, I need to remove duplicate parts.

How am I able to get the columns that have the merged list like below?

Source:

```
     col_0      col_a      col_b      col_c

0      aa        [1]        NaN       [2,3]
1      bb       [a, b]     [b, c]      [c]
2      cc        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Expected:

```
     col_0      col_a      col_b      col_c     merged_a_to_c

0      aa        [1]        NaN       [2,3]        [1,2,3]
1      bb       [a, b]     [b, c]      [c]        [a, b, c]
2      cc        NaN        NaN        NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def merge(df):
    merged_a_to_c = []
    for row in range(len(df)):
        merge_tmp = []
        for columns in range(len(df.columns)):
            if type(df.iloc[row, columns]) == list: 
                for element in df.iloc[row, columns]:
                    if element not in merge_tmp:
                        merge_tmp.append(element)
                
        if merge_tmp != []:
            merged_a_to_c.append(merge_tmp)
        else:
            merged_a_to_c.append(np.nan)
    
    df['merged_a_to_c'] = merged_a_to_c
    return(df)
```

```py
  col_0   col_a   col_b   col_c merged_a_to_c
0    aa     [1]     NaN  [2, 3]     [1, 2, 3]
1    bb  [a, b]  [b, c]     [c]     [a, b, c]
2    cc     NaN     NaN     NaN           NaN
```

You can use this code regardless of the size(column lengths, row lengths) of dataframes.

I edited some codes cuz I didn't realize that I should concern the duplicate problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can just concatenate them with `+`:

```
df['merged_a_to_c'] = df['col_a'] + df['col_c']
```

Or for multiple columns (filling NaNs with empty lists first):

```
for col in ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'...]:
    df['merged_a_to_c'] += df[col].apply(lambda d: d if isinstance(d, list) else [])
```

If you want to remove duplicates, an efficient way is to filter out NaNs and then apply `set`:

```
mask = ~df['merged_a_to_c'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'merged_a_to_c'] = df.loc[mask, 'merged_a_to_c'].map(set)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I have a lot of columns to merge, then how do I treat them?

Comment: I expanded my answer to include this

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But just `[1] + NaN + [2, 3]` result in `NaN`. The idea for removing duplicates is still good.

Comment: I added a fix for this: temporarily filling NaNs eith empty lists

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by others reply, I can solved this problem with more simple code.

Thanks!

```
cols = ["col_a", "col_b", "col_c"]
df["merged_a_to_c"] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.fillna({i: [] for i in df.index})).sum(axis=1)
df["merged_a_to_c"] = df["merged_a_to_c"].apply(lambda y: np.nan if len(y)==0 else y)
```